# Magento 2.0.x Remove Account Tab in Mobile Menu

Tags: overrides, magento-2.0, navigation, mobile

### Summary:

I'd like to remove the entire Account tab from the Magento 2.0.x mobile menu. Our site doesn't have accounts for users, it's more like a catalog with no purchasing.

I've found many examples of how to remove items from the Account tab, but none to remove the tab itself.

### Steps already taken:

- I'm working in developer mode with cache disabled.
- I've overridden `app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml` to remove the `customer_account_navigation` block, but the menu still shows:

e.g. `<my_theme_dir>/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

- I've tried removing the block in `default.xml` in the same folder above. Didn't work.
- I've done a `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `bin/magento cache:clear` after updating the XML just to be sure that wasn't required. Neither helped.
- I've hunted all throughout the code base to find anything related to "Account" or the navigation menu. Nothing I found and changed removed the tab.

### Questions:

1. Am I overriding the correct file?
2. Am I overriding it in the correct location in my theme directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this code in you active theme's `default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
   <referenceBlock name="store.links" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

And run command

```
 - php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Knowing where the theme's default.xml is located is tricky to a newbie. We ended up editing default.xml located in <theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml. This worked, but is there another default.xml you are referencing?

Comment: No, just make sure that make this changes in active theme `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

First copy the whole `customer_account.xml` with content to your theme. and before the  tag just add `<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation" remove="true" />` . It's worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_account_navigation_block" template="Magento_Theme::html/collapsible.phtml" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account Dashboard</argument>
                    <argument name="block_css" xsi:type="string">block-collapsible-nav</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">nav items</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Dashboard</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```